# CreateFileA Visit a windows file system driver returned INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

Tags: windows, driver

I writed a file system demo most likely fast fat ,but when I use CreateFileA to call my dirver ,it gives an INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE result . I have checked the driver `s  IRP dispatches and found no DbgPrint setting in the function entries triggered .
This is the user mode  code:

```
 public IntPtr LoadDriver(string lpFileName)
        {
            int error = 0;

            string openName = string.Format("\\\\.\\{0}", EXE_DRIVER_NAME);
            IntPtr hSCManager = WinAPI.OpenSCManager(null, null,
            WinAPI.SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE);

            if (IntPtr.Zero != hSCManager)
            {

                //创建服务
                IntPtr hService = WinAPI.CreateService(hSCManager, EXE_DRIVER_NAME,
                    DISPLAY_NAME, WinAPI.SERVICE_START,
                    WinAPI.SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER, WinAPI.SERVICE_DEMAND_START,
                    WinAPI.SERVICE_ERROR_IGNORE, lpFileName, null, IntPtr.Zero, null, null, null);

                if (WinAPI.ERROR_SERVICE_EXISTS == WinAPI.GetLastError())
                {
                    hService = WinAPI.OpenService(hSCManager, EXE_DRIVER_NAME, WinAPI.SERVICE_START);
                }
                error = WinAPI.GetLastError();
                if(error!=0)
                {
                    dumpErrorCode("OpenService失败 ", error);

                }

                int startflag = WinAPI.StartService(hService, 0, 0);
                if (startflag == 0)
                {
                    error = WinAPI.GetLastError();
                    if (error != WinAPI.ERROR_SERVICE_ALREADY_RUNNING)  //已经启动
                    {
                        dumpErrorCode("StartService失败", error);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                          MessageBox.Show("服务已经启动");
                    }
                }

 //               WinAPI.CloseServiceHandle(hService);
 //               WinAPI.CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
                MessageBox.Show(openName);
                try
                {
                    hDriver = WinAPI.CreateFileA(openName, WinAPI.GENERIC_READ , 0, IntPtr.Zero, WinAPI.OPEN_EXISTING, null, IntPtr.Zero);


                    if (hDriver == (IntPtr)(-1))
                    {
                        dumpErrorCode("获取文件句柄失败 ", error);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("成功创建驱动");
                        //his.OpenDriverEvent();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
                }
            }
            return hDriver;
        }
```

This is the driver`s entry point  code:

```
NTSTATUS
DriverEntry(
    _In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject,
    _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath
    )
{
    NTSTATUS Status;
    UNICODE_STRING UnicodeString;
    FS_FILTER_CALLBACKS FilterCallbacks;

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( RegistryPath );
    DbgPrint("\nThis is HRFS Driver Entry\n");
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&UnicodeString, L"\\fastFatDemo");
    gSFilterDriverObject = DriverObject;

    Status = IoCreateDevice( DriverObject,
                             0,
                             &UnicodeString,
                             FILE_DEVICE_DISK_FILE_SYSTEM,
                             0,
                             FALSE,
                             &HrfsDiskFileSystemDeviceObject );

    if (!NT_SUCCESS( Status )) {
        return Status;
    }
    DbgPrint("HRFS device HRFS created\n ");
    DriverObject->DriverUnload = FatUnload;

    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE]                   = (PDRIVER_DISPATCH)FatFsdCreate;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CLOSE]                    = (PDRIVER_DISPATCH)HrfsFsdClose;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_READ]                     = (PDRIVER_DISPATCH)FatFsdRead;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_WRITE]                    = (PDRIVER_DISPATCH)FatFsdWrite;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION]        = (PDRIVER_DISPATCH)FatFsdQueryInformation;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION]          = (PDRIVER_DISPATCH)FatFsdSetInformation;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_QUERY_EA]                 = (PDRIVER_DISPATCH)FatFsdQueryEa;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_SET_EA]                   = (PDRIVER_DISPATCH)FatFsdSetEa;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_FLUSH_BUFFERS]            = (PDRIVER_DISPATCH)FatFsdFlushBuffers;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION] = (PDRIVER_DISPATCH)FatFsdQueryVolumeInformation;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_SET_VOLUME_INFORMATION]   = (PDRIVER_DISPATCH)FatFsdSetVolumeInformation;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CLEANUP]                  = (PDRIVER_DISPATCH)FatFsdCleanup;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL]        = (PDRIVER_DISPATCH)FatFsdDirectoryControl;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_FILE_SYSTEM_CONTROL]      = (PDRIVER_DISPATCH)FatFsdFileSystemControl;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_LOCK_CONTROL]             = (PDRIVER_DISPATCH)FatFsdLockControl;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL]           = (PDRIVER_DISPATCH)FatFsdDeviceControl;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_SHUTDOWN]                 = (PDRIVER_DISPATCH)FatFsdShutdown;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_PNP]                      = (PDRIVER_DISPATCH)FatFsdPnp;
    DbgPrint("HRFS device HRFS MajorFunction created\n ");
    DriverObject->FastIoDispatch = NULL;
    DbgPrint("HRFS device HRFS FatFastIoDispatch created\n ");
    RtlZeroMemory(&FatFastIoDispatch, sizeof(FatFastIoDispatch));

    FatFastIoDispatch.SizeOfFastIoDispatch =    sizeof(FAST_IO_DISPATCH);
    FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoCheckIfPossible =   FALSE;  //  CheckForFastIo
    FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoRead = FALSE;             //  Read
    FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoWrite = FALSE;            //  Write
    FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoQueryBasicInfo = FALSE;     //  QueryBasicInfo
    FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoQueryStandardInfo = FALSE;       //  QueryStandardInfo
    FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoLock = FALSE;               //  Lock
    FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoUnlockSingle = FALSE;       //  UnlockSingle
    FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoUnlockAll = FALSE;          //  UnlockAll
    FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoUnlockAllByKey = FALSE;     //  UnlockAllByKey
    FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoQueryNetworkOpenInfo = FALSE;
    FatFastIoDispatch.AcquireForCcFlush = FALSE;
    FatFastIoDispatch.ReleaseForCcFlush = FALSE;
    FatFastIoDispatch.MdlRead = FALSE;
    FatFastIoDispatch.MdlReadComplete = FALSE;
    FatFastIoDispatch.PrepareMdlWrite = FALSE;
    FatFastIoDispatch.MdlWriteComplete = FALSE;


    //FatFastIoDispatch.SizeOfFastIoDispatch = sizeof(FAST_IO_DISPATCH);
    //FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoCheckIfPossible = FatFastIoCheckIfPossible;  //  CheckForFastIo
    //FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoRead = FsRtlCopyRead;             //  Read
    //FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoWrite = FsRtlCopyWrite;            //  Write
    //FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoQueryBasicInfo = FatFastQueryBasicInfo;     //  QueryBasicInfo
    //FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoQueryStandardInfo = FatFastQueryStdInfo;       //  QueryStandardInfo
    //FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoLock = FatFastLock;               //  Lock
    //FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoUnlockSingle = FatFastUnlockSingle;       //  UnlockSingle
    //FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoUnlockAll = FatFastUnlockAll;          //  UnlockAll
    //FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoUnlockAllByKey = FatFastUnlockAllByKey;     //  UnlockAllByKey
    //FatFastIoDispatch.FastIoQueryNetworkOpenInfo = FatFastQueryNetworkOpenInfo;
    //FatFastIoDispatch.AcquireForCcFlush = HrfsAcquireForCcFlush;
    //FatFastIoDispatch.ReleaseForCcFlush = HrfsReleaseForCcFlush;
    //FatFastIoDispatch.MdlRead = FsRtlMdlReadDev;
    //FatFastIoDispatch.MdlReadComplete = FsRtlMdlReadCompleteDev;
    //FatFastIoDispatch.PrepareMdlWrite = FsRtlPrepareMdlWriteDev;
    //FatFastIoDispatch.MdlWriteComplete = FsRtlMdlWriteCompleteDev;





   /*  FsFilter通知回调例程在下层文件系统执行某些操作之前或之后调用。
       如果需要获取更多有关于FsFilter回调例程相关信息，可参见FsRtlRegisterFileSystemFilterCallbacks例程 
       为了注册FsFilter的通知回调例程必须分配并初始化FS_FILTER_CALLBACKS结构体，然后向该结构体中促出FsFilter回调例程，
       并将存储有Callbacks parameter到FsRtlRegisterFileSystemFilterCallbacks中。*/

    RtlZeroMemory( &FilterCallbacks,
                   sizeof(FS_FILTER_CALLBACKS) );

    FilterCallbacks.SizeOfFsFilterCallbacks = sizeof(FS_FILTER_CALLBACKS);
    FilterCallbacks.PreAcquireForSectionSynchronization = HrfsFilterCallbackAcquireForCreateSection;

    Status = FsRtlRegisterFileSystemFilterCallbacks( DriverObject,
                                                     &FilterCallbacks );

    if (!NT_SUCCESS( Status )) {

        IoDeleteDevice( HrfsDiskFileSystemDeviceObject );

        return Status;
    }
     DbgPrint("HRFS device HRFS FilterCallbacks registed\n ");


    RtlZeroMemory( &HrfsData, sizeof(FAT_DATA));

    HrfsData.NodeTypeCode = HRFS_NTC_DATA_HEADER;
    HrfsData.NodeByteSize = sizeof(FAT_DATA);

    InitializeListHead(&HrfsData.VcbQueue);

    pDriverObject = DriverObject;
    HrfsData.DiskFileSystemDeviceObject = HrfsDiskFileSystemDeviceObject;


    //
    //  This list head keeps track of closes yet to be done.
    //

    InitializeListHead( &HrfsData.AsyncCloseList );
    InitializeListHead( &HrfsData.DelayedCloseList );

    HrfsData.FatCloseItem = IoAllocateWorkItem( HrfsDiskFileSystemDeviceObject);

    if (HrfsData.FatCloseItem == NULL) {
        IoDeleteDevice (HrfsDiskFileSystemDeviceObject);

        return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    }
    DbgPrint("HRFS device HRFS workitem created\n ");
    //
    //  Allocate the zero page
    //

    HrfsData.ZeroPage = ExAllocatePoolWithTag( NonPagedPoolNx, PAGE_SIZE, 'ZtaF' );
    if (HrfsData.ZeroPage == NULL) {
        IoDeleteDevice (HrfsDiskFileSystemDeviceObject);

        return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    }
    RtlZeroMemory( HrfsData.ZeroPage, PAGE_SIZE );


    //
    //  Now initialize our general purpose spinlock (gag) and figure out how
    //  deep and wide we want our delayed lists (along with fooling ourselves
    //  about the lookaside depths).
    //

    KeInitializeSpinLock( &HrfsData.GeneralSpinLock );


    HrfsData.CacheManagerCallbacks.AcquireForLazyWrite  = &HrfsAcquireFcbForLazyWrite;
    HrfsData.CacheManagerCallbacks.ReleaseFromLazyWrite = &HrfsReleaseFcbFromLazyWrite;
    HrfsData.CacheManagerCallbacks.AcquireForReadAhead  = &HrfsAcquireFcbForReadAhead;
    HrfsData.CacheManagerCallbacks.ReleaseFromReadAhead = &HrfsReleaseFcbFromReadAhead;

    HrfsData.CacheManagerNoOpCallbacks.AcquireForLazyWrite  = &HrfsNoOpAcquire;
    HrfsData.CacheManagerNoOpCallbacks.ReleaseFromLazyWrite = &HrfsNoOpRelease;
    HrfsData.CacheManagerNoOpCallbacks.AcquireForReadAhead  = &HrfsNoOpAcquire;
    HrfsData.CacheManagerNoOpCallbacks.ReleaseFromReadAhead = &HrfsNoOpRelease;

    //
    //  Set up global pointer to our process.
    //

    HrfsData.OurProcess = PsGetCurrentProcess();
    DbgPrint("HRFS device HRFS our process getted\n ");
    // 
    //  Setup the number of processors we support for statistics as the current number 
    //  running.
    //

#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_VISTA)
    HrfsData.NumberProcessors = KeQueryActiveProcessorCount( NULL );
#else
    HrfsData.NumberProcessors = KeNumberProcessors;
#endif


    DbgPrint("HrfsData.NumberProcessors :%d", HrfsData.NumberProcessors);
    ExInitializeResourceLite( &HrfsData.Resource );
    IoRegisterFileSystem(HrfsDiskFileSystemDeviceObject);
    ObReferenceObject (HrfsDiskFileSystemDeviceObject);
    DbgPrint("Device HRFS HrfsDiskFileSystemDeviceObject registed\n ");


    return( STATUS_SUCCESS );
}
```

Comment: You may use `QueryDosDevice()` to check which pseudo-files in `\\.\ ` are present. Did you already check if `\\.\xxx` exists? As far as I remember, in Windows 2000 you had to create a device. The actual device's name was `\Devices\xxx` (in kernel space). Then you had to create a symbolic link to that device in `\DosDevices`. The pseudo-directory `\\.\ ` in the user space applications equals `\DosDevices` in kernel space. Maybe this is no longer true in Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks , My platform is  Win7 x64   Do I  need to add something in my driver code to add device name into "\DosDevice"  ?

Comment: [This web site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/introduction-to-ms-dos-device-names) might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much !  I think this may be very helpful for this issue and I will try it !

Comment: @MartinRosenau  I `m very glad to tell you the message  .It can resolve  the INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE problem  Thank you very very much !